# How can I load multiples html files into a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here's my case, I've been working on online manual for the company that I work and recently I decide to make it look better by changing some visual elements, so I thought, why not use bootstrap, and So I did.
Here's the thing, I have a tree-view where I have each part (titles) of the manual, and those titles load an HTML file where I have the information and links to CSS file.
I used to load the content into an Iframe, but that seems to be a terrible idea for all the problems I've deal with it trying to apply CSS, So I decided I'll use DIV'S instead of the Iframe.

Here goes the question:

**IS THERE ANY WAY TO LOAD ALL MULTIPLE HTML FILES INTO A SINGLE DIV BY CLICKING EACH TIME A TITLE?**

Because All the titles are contained in a "a" tag, and then I use to target it into the Iframe, but now it's not that easy with DIV'S

I've try a little bit of JavaScript and nothing, with Jquery the only thing I've done it's making a function and that function load a specific html file, and by trying adding some parameters to it and it doesn't recognized the path for those HTML files, and it happens the same with InnerHTML.

**PD: Those files are locally hosted in a server where they are displayed**

Here's a little bit of what I got...

JS:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#content').load('intro.html')
        });
     </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <ul id="tree3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">          
            <li><a href="PATHFILE_1">TITLE 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="PATHFILE_2">TITLE 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="PATHFILE_3">TITLE 3</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
       </div>
</div>
```

And a want to display all the FILES into this div:

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="content">
      HERE THE HTML FILES
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What scripting tools such as php or perl or ... would you like to use?

Comment: @MarkStewart he don't need server side, just need to load the HTML files using ajax

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you add a class to the `a` elements you want to load on the div, for instance `class='dynamic'`. Set a click handler to all those `a.dynamic` elements, get the link by using the href attribute of the target, and use preventDefault so the default behaviour (navigating) is not triggered:

```
$(body).on("click", "a.dynamic", function(event) {
  $('#content').load(event.target.href);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Remember to add the class on the links:

```
<a class="dynamic" href="PATHFILE_2">TITLE 2</a>
```

Note that your dynamically loaded HTML should have only the partial content, no `html` or `body` tags. That being said, it's better to not use `a` elements to trigger the load:

```
<div class="dynamic" data-href="PATHFILE_2">TITLE 2</div>
```

And retrieve the url with this:

```
$('#content').load(event.target.dataset.href);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot load multiple HTML files in one `div` container.

But why don't you just use multiple `div` elements inside your `#content`? You can generate those `divs` dynamically when one of the hyperlinks is clicked. Each `div` will then load up one of your HTML files.

The HTML structure stays the same as you have posted it above. 
In JavaScript / jQuery it would look something like this:

```js
$('#tree3').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 

  // clear the entire content div
  $('#content').empty(); 

  let parentLi = $(this).closest("li"); 

  // load the HTML content for the hyperlink that has been clicked.
  let dynamicDiv = $('<div></div>'); 
  $('#content').append(dynamicDiv); 
  dynamicDiv.load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
    // done loading the main HTML content 
  });

  // check if there is a list inside the li element
  let subList = parentLi.children("ul");
  if(subList.length && subList.length > 0){
    $.each(subList.children("li"), function(k, v){
      let subLi = $(v); 
      let hyperlink = $('a', subLi).attr('href'); 

      // load the HTML content for each of the sub entries
      let dynamicDiv = $('<div></div>'); 
      $('#content').append(dynamicDiv); 
      dynamicDiv.load(hyperlink, function(){
        // done loading...
      });
    });
  }
});
```

If you want to have more than two levels in your list, you can modify the code and make it recursive. So instead of iterating through the `li` elements of the `subList` once, you would have to check whether those `li` elements contain other `subLists` recursively. The overall logic for generating the `divs` and loading up the HTML content would stay the same.

For styling purposes I recommend giving the main `#content` container an `overflow-y: auto`. This way you only have a single scrollbar for the entire content. The `divs` that are generated dynamically will adjust their height according to the HTML content.